# The type '*', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element could not be found

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, azure, remote-event-receiver

I have created my provider hosted app and successfully debugged it locally and it works perfect, its ready for the test environment

But when I deploy it to Azure I have this error in the Web service:

```
The type 'MyCompanyName.IntranetWeb.Services.AppEventReceiver', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
```

The URL is this: (at least I should see the Web service page, right)

```
http://pru-MyCompanyName-intranet.azurewebsites.net/AppEventReceiver.svc
```

Project structure here: you can see the root has the web service.
http://screencast.com/t/Q8XEzjkBPG

My web.config is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientId" value="f4fcb686-xx-4938-a676-a1ba50c202e5" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="ljguTvxHR+xx+Pl1IMg1Hjt5rsQ=" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!--Used by app for SharePoint-->
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

the webservice markupp

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyCompanyName.IntranetWeb.Services.AppEventReceiver" CodeBehind="AppEventReceiver.svc.cs" %>
```

the webservice first line

```
namespace MyCompanyName.IntranetWeb.Services
{
    public class AppEventReceiver : IRemoteEventService
    {
```

Comment: I used dotPeek to disassemble and the class and service are there http://screencast.com/t/AiFeV8iMui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the solution was very simple, the Sharepoint Client Dlls, were not set to Copy Local True, it was false.  Changing this flag fixed my problem.

http://www.luisevalencia.com/2015/02/25/deploy-sharepoint-app-to-azure-gives-the-type-provided-as-the-service-attribute-value-in-the-servicehost-directive-or-provided-in-the-configuration-element-could-not-be-found/